# How do I set the command line arguments in a C program so that it's visible when users type "ps aux"?

Tags: c, posix, argv, ps

When you type "ps aux" the ps command shows command arguments that the program was run with. Some programs change this as a way of indicating status. I've tried changing argv[] fields and it doesn't seem to work. Is there a standard way to set the command line arguments so that they appear when the user types ps?

That is, this doesn't work:

```
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    argv[0] = "Hi Mom!";
    sleep(100);
}

09:40 imac3:~$ ./x &
[2] 96087
09:40 imac3:~$ ps uxp 96087 
USER      PID  %CPU %MEM      VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED      TIME COMMAND
yv32      96087   0.0  0.0  2426560    324 s001  S     9:40AM   0:00.00 ./x
09:40 imac3:~$ cat x.c
```

Comment: I think ythis is some kind of thing called "bash tab extension". You need to define a tab extension handler for your program and register it in some file, but don't ask me how to do this.

Comment: Not possible? ( http://www.steve.org.uk/Reference/Unix/faq_2.html#SEC22 ) You might also like ( http://www.netsplit.com/2007/01/10/hiding-arguments-from-ps/ )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had the right idea, but you don't change the *pointers* in `argv[n]`, you must change the string pointed to by `argv[0]` itself:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    size_t maxlen = strlen(argv[0]);

    memset(argv[0], 0, maxlen);
    strncat(argv[0], "Hi Mom!", maxlen);
    pause();

    return 0;
}
```

(Note that whether or not this actually changes the command name shown by `ps` is system-dependent).

Comment: @R..: No it's not. Combined with `strlen`, @caf is making a very careful observation that we might not be guaranteed to have more space than the original `argv[0]` to store our program name. Also, the `memset` isn't necessary, `strncat` will always null terminate. Very clean answer, nice use of `pause()`.

Comment: Look again. `strncat` is being used to concatenate to a zero-length string, i.e. as a cheap `strlcpy` instead of for actual concatenation. The `memset` is unnecessary, but you'd at least need `argv[0][0]=0;` to replace it for the desired functionality. This nonobviousness is why I said it's strange.

Comment: @vy32 Not really broken, just misused, misunderstood and their rationale long forgotten...

Comment: @vy32 - The UB happens only if you misuse the not null-terminated char arrays. But if that is what you need, then all is well.

Comment: @vy32: ...and `strncat()` always null-terminates its result, anyway.

Comment: @caf, you are right, `strncat()` and `strncpy()` differ in that manner. These inconsistencies are quite annoying. I'll remove my comment.