# How to set command line value via Ruby to see status via PS?

Tags: ruby, command-line, command-line-arguments, argv

I'd like to provide feedback for my pinger program via the command line and view it using ps ax.

I found a [SO q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760896/how-do-i-set-the-command-line-arguments-in-a-c-program-so-that-its-visible-when). But

```
....
ARGV[0] = "Hello!" # does nothing
```

I'm starting the script via `ruby ./pinger`

Comment: I doubt you could do that w/o modifying Ruby itself.

Comment: @Dave: You can assign to `$0`, that's the Ruby equivalent of C's `argv[0]`, Ruby's `ARGV` just holds the arguments.

Comment: @Dave: This `$0` stuff is probably [inherited from Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24PROGRAM_NAME).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assign to `$0` instead. For example, if I start `irb` and

```
$ ps | egrep 'irb|pancakes'
 3119 ttys000    0:01.02 irb 
 3131 ttys001    0:00.00 egrep irb|pancakes
```

and then over in `irb`:

```
>> $0 = 'pancakes'
```

and back to the other terminal:

```
$ ps | egrep 'irb|pancakes'
 3119 ttys000    0:01.07 pancakes 
 3135 ttys001    0:00.00 egrep irb|pancakes
```

You can check with this tiny script as well:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
$0 = 'pancakes'
sleep 10
```

Run that, jump to another terminal, do a `ps | grep pancakes`, and you should see a pancakes process.

Comment: @rm-rf: I got tired of *foo* so I switched to [*pancakes*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJUvPZI3Cr4). Besides, I like pancakes  :)